# Responsive textbox layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, textbox

Is anyone able to provide some help with this issue,

attached below is the code for my site with two images,

the first image shows the textbox position in normal desktop web browser,

the second images shows the textbox in mobile view, as you can see the text box does not stay the same size and moves up to the top of the page,

I want the entire page to keep its desktop look even when in mobile view (any mobile)i want those white text boxes to reach the footer almost, with the two buttons "next" and "back" sitting just above the footer,

many thanks

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="toptext"> 
<h1> GET A QUOTE</h1>
<h2> RETRIEVE A QUOTE</h2>
<h3>NEED HELP OR ADVICE?CALL US <br style>  </h3>
    <h4> 0800 0481804</h4>
    </div>

   <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <div class="box"> 

<div id="content">
<img src="10.png" class="images" />
<img src="10000.png" class="images" />
<img src="replacement.png" class="images" />
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="box1"> 


<div> <img src="laptop.png" class="laptop"> </div>
<p>The CSS box model is essentially a box that wraps around every HTML 
element. It consists of: borders, padding, margins, and the actual content.
</p>

<div class="bottomtext">Please enter a figure for the number of individual 
laptops/macbooks that you would like to insure in each price range. <br> Where 
you dont want cover with a particular price range, please leave bank.</div>
</div> 





<button type="button" class="button" onclick="alert('Back!')">Back</button>
<button type="button" class="But" onclick="alert('Next!')">Next</button>
<div class="footer">
<p> © Insync Insurance Solutions Ltd 2016 All rights reserved. Mobiru is a 
trading style of Insync Insurance Solutions Ltd which is authorised and 
regulated by the Financial Conduct Authority. Our registered office is Midland 
House, 2 Poole Road, Bournemouth, Dorset BH2 5QY and we are registered in 
England under company number 08810662. Should you have cause to complain, and 
you are not satisfied with our response to your complaint, you may be able to 
refer it to the Financial Ombudsman Service, which can be contacted as f 
follows: The Financial Ombudsman Service Exchange Tower, London, E14 9SR | 
Tel: 0800 023 4567 or 0300 123 9 123 | www.financial-ombudsman.org.uk </p>
      <img src="Logo-Trans.png" class="logo1">
</div>

 body {
 background-color: black;
 }
 #logo {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 }
 h1
 {
  color: white;
  position:absolute;
  right:25rem;
  top:2.5rem;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 }
 h2
 {
 color: white;
 position:absolute;
 right:15rem;
 top:2.5rem;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 }
 h3
 {
 color: white;
 position:absolute;
 right:2rem;
 top:1.5rem;
 font-size: 7px;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 }

 h4
 {
 color: white;
 position:absolute;
  right:2rem;
 top:1.5rem;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 }

 .footer {
  position: fixed;

 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height:110px;
 background-color: #333;
 color: white;


 }

img.logo {
height: 100px;
 }
 img.logo1 {
 height: 40px;
 left:3em;

 bottom:2rem;
 position:absolute;
 }

 p {
 font-size: 6px;
 position:fixed;
 bottom:2rem;
 right:15em;
 width:500px;
 max-width: 400px;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 }

  button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;

  color: white;

  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;

     bottom:7.5rem;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;

  position: fixed;
 margin: auto;
 left: 8rem;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: -28rem;
 width: 100px; /* width of button */
 height: 30px;
 }

  Button.But {
background-color: #4CAF50;
 border: none;
 color: white;

  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;

  bottom:7.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: fixed;
 margin: auto;
 left: -5rem;
right: 0;
 bottom: -28rem;

 width: 100px; /* width of button */
 height: 30px;


 }
 img.arrow {
 max-height: 40px;
 }

 .box {
 background-color: white;
 max-width:100%;
 height: 150px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding:25px;
 margin: 25px;

  }
 .box1 {
 background-color: white;
 max-width:100%;
 height:150px;
 padding: 25px;
 margin: 25px;
 border-radius: 5px;

 }

img.laptop { 

height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left:0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 12rem;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto; 
}
.bottomtext {
position: absolute;
bottom: 50px;

}

img.textimage
{
height:20px;
left:8rem;
position: absolute;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.images {
display: inline;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
vertical-align:middle;
width:200px;
}
#content {
display: block;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
position: relative;
top: 90px;
height: auto;
max-width: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x:auto;
word-wrap:normal;
white-space:nowrap;
height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Why dont you make it responsive instead? Btw, you can achieve that using display block or using positions absolute and bottom 0

Comment: Hi luis, thanks for answering.  Would you be able to elaborate a bit on your answer

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

```css
body {
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
p {
 font-size: 6px;
 position:fixed;
 bottom:2rem;
 right:15em;
 width:500px;
 max-width: 400px;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 }

.bottomtext {
width:400px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
 .bottomtext {
 width: 200px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div> <img src="laptop.png" class="laptop"> </div>
<p>The CSS box model is essentially a box that wraps around every HTML 
element. It consists of: borders, padding, margins, and the actual content.
</p>

<div class="bottomtext">Please enter a figure for the number of individual 
laptops/macbooks that you would like to insure in each price range. <br> Where 
you dont want cover with a particular price range, please leave bank.</div>
```

So anything lower than a width of 550px will apply. In this case, it will make the width of the class bottom text = 200px;